# Is there a way to pass a composed key for a dictionary as argument of a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a function that should use the value of the key that we pass as argument. The key would lookup the value in a nested dictionary. Ex:

nested_dict = ... # dump from json a very nested dictionary

```
def get_value(nested_dict, composed_key):
    # ? nested_dict[composed_key]
```

Is there a way to do this :

```
get_value(nested_dict, ["level1"]["level2"]...["leveln"])
```

Or :

```
get_value(nested_dict, "level1.level2...leveln")
```

?

How can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a list of the keys as second argument like this:

```
def get_value(nested_dict, composed_key):
  for x in composed_key:
    print(nested_dict[x])
```

And call like:

```
get_value(nested_dict, ["level1","level2",...,"leveln"])
```

Comment: Unfortunately not working